# How to turn off verbose stacktraces in Flash Builder?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, flash-builder

I have been trying to create a debug version of an `AIR` desktop runtime and seem to have somehow permanently turned on `verbose-stacktraces`. I am using `Flash Builder` and was playing with `adl` through the Terminal (OSX).

In `Flash Builder` for a test project I had the compiler option set to:

> -locale en_US -swf-version=21 -debug=true -verbose-stacktraces=true

And was getting continuous console output like this:

> 2301 AVMINF: MTHD spark.primitives.supportClasses::GraphicElement/get drawY ()
>   2301 AVMINF: MTHD spark.primitives.supportClasses::GraphicElement/get displayObjectSharingMode ()
>   2301 AVMINF: MTHD spark.primitives.supportClasses::GraphicElement/get y ()
>   2301 AVMINF: MTHD flash.geom::Point ()
>   2301 AVMINF: MTHD spark.primitives.supportClasses::StrokedElement/get stroke ()

I set `-verbose-stacktraces=false`, tried it, and then removed that directive completely, but I still get the console dump. Worse, I created a new test project and am getting the verbose console dump for that.

What did I do and how do I undo it?

I'm supporting a legacy Flex project and use Flex and Flash Builder rarely now so my knowledge has rusted and blown away.

Comment: Have you tried removing '-debug=true' ?

Comment: @Chris - yes, tried that but still get the verbose output. Odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll always see console output and verbose stacktraces for swfs compiled with `-debug=true`.

> If you set this option to true, Flex also sets the verbose-stacktraces
>   option to true

[Here's the docs.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html)

If you want to avoid console output. Just "Run" the app instead of launching it in debug mode.

[Run vs Debug Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-15a3a08712e93a1ff8e-8000.html)

Edit: I think I figured out what you did.
Try going into your [mm.cfg](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fc9.html) and changing (or removing) this setting:

```
AS3Trace = 1 // should be AS3Trace = 0
```

Reference: https://jpauclair.net/2010/02/10/mmcfg-treasure/

Comment: Thanks! Turned out that I had enabled `AS3Trace` in a GLOBAL "mm.cfg" file (i.e. not at the root of my user directory but at the `Library/Application Support/Macromedia` path of the OSX system). What a cruise to nowhere . . . thanks again!